# dataframe pivoting and adding and convert category into columns with prefix

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to transform this Dataframe.

[image]

To look like the following:

[image]

Here is the code to create the sample df

```html
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [[1, 'A', 0, '2021-07-01'],
                         [1, 'B', 1, '2021-07-02'],
                         [2, 'D', 3, '2021-07-02'],
                         [2, 'C', 2, '2021-07-02'],
                         [2, 'E', 4, '2021-07-02']
                        ], columns = ['id', 'symbol', 'value', 'date'])

symbol_list = [['A', 'B', ''], ['C','D','E']]
```

The end result dataframe is grouped by id field with symbol column turns into multiple columns with symbol ordering mapped to the user input list.

I was using .apply() method to construct each datarow for the above dataframe but it is taking very long time for 10000+ datapoints.

I am trying to find a more efficient way to transform the dataframe. I am thinking that I will need to use pivot function to unstack the data frame with the combination of resetting index (to turn category value into column). Appreciate any help on this!

Comment: Please add the function you tried for `apply`. Will you always have max 3 symbols \ values?

Comment: Can there be multiple rows with the same id and symbol/value?

Is the ordering per id? For example, could id 1 and 2 have the same symbol, but the ordering of the symbol differs?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) for reshape, then extract `date` by [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) with max per rows, flatten columns and last add new column `date` by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [[1, 'A', 0, '2021-07-01'],
                         [1, 'B', 1, '2021-07-02'],
                         [2, 'D', 3, '2021-07-02'],
                         [2, 'C', 2, '2021-07-02'],
                         [2, 'E', 4, '2021-07-02']
                        ], columns = ['id', 'symbol', 'value', 'date'])

#IMPORTANT all values from symbol_list  are in column symbol (without empty strings)
symbol_list = [['A', 'B', ''], ['C','D','E']]

order = [y for x in symbol_list for y in x if y]
print (order)
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

#convert all values to Categoricals with specified order by flatten lists
df['symbol'] = pd.Categorical(df['symbol'], ordered=True, categories=order)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

#sorting by id and symbol
df = df.sort_values(['id','symbol'])
df1 = df.set_index(['id',df.groupby('id').cumcount()]).unstack()

date_max = df1.pop('date').max(axis=1)
df1.columns = df1.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}')
df1 = df1.assign(date = date_max)
print (df1)
   symbol_0 symbol_1 symbol_2  value_0  value_1  value_2       date
id                                                                 
1         A        B      NaN      0.0      1.0      NaN 2021-07-02
2         C        D        E      2.0      3.0      4.0 2021-07-02
```

Comment: Thanks! this is very close to what I am looking for! One missing part is that I also want to order symbols in symbol_0, 1, 2 as well as their corresponding values according to the user input ordering list.

Comment: @Dancoding - For each `id` is defined list? Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Dancoding - So it means in nested lists are order of all Symbol? So possible use edited answer?